# Write to MAC's serial port to talk to Arduino (fopen( /dev/tty.usbmodem1431) hangs forver)

Tags: macos, arduino

I have a problem with TTY device on MAC. I created a script which talks to Arduino and works well on Linux. Problem I'm having with MAC is I can't "fopen" the device. For example, if I do

```
echo "foo" > /dev/tty.usbmodem1431
```

It hangs forever blocking the port. It works well from Arduino's Serial Monitor so theoretically I should be able talking to it.

**OK. I found the solution. I have to write to**

```
/dev/cu.usbmodem1431
```

I still don't know why TTY don't want to work.

Comment: Which COM port are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand question. I use "/dev/tty.usbmodem1431"

Comment: Which Arduino Board are you using. You might be using the wrong port. See here for more info. http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/MacOSX#toc8

Comment: I use correct port which is the one I posted in my question. I believe it's the correct one because it works well from the Arduino IDE.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632586/macos-whats-the-difference-between-dev-tty-and-dev-cu
for why cu works when tty does not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tty with:

```
stty -f /dev/tty.usbmodem1431 cs8 115200 ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke noflsh -ixon -crtscts

echo "hello" > /dev/tty.usbmodem1431
```

Where 115200 is your Serial.begin speed.

Answer (score 1):

What speed are you using? The default speed of Max OSX is 9600. Give it a try (when you set serial in your arduino program).  stty does not seem to change the speed as one would expect.