# Opening a serial port on OS X hangs forever without O_NONBLOCK flag

Tags: c, macos, serial-port, termios, stty

I have a serial to USB converter (FTDI, drivers installed from http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) connecting a serial device to a MacBook Air. It shows up on the MacBook as both `/dev/cu.usbserial-A4017CQY` and `/dev/tty.usbserial-A4017CQY`. <s>All behaviour I describe is identical regardless of which of these two I use.</s>

**Edit: Using `/dev/cu.*` did solve the problem. I'm not sure why it seemed not to work when I first posted this question. Thanks to duskwuff for pointing me in the right direction, though he has his TTY names backwards: `/dev/tty.*` will wait for flow control, while `/dev/cu.*` will not.**

The first problem I encountered was that the syscall to `open()` would block forever if I did not use the `O_NONBLOCK` flag. Using the flag, I get a good file descriptor, but `write()` does not seem to actually write (though it returns just fine claiming to have written the bytes), and `read()` fails with the error "Resource temporarily unavailable".

`stty -af /dev/cu.usbserial-A4017CQY` shows the settings just fine, but if I try to change them with a command like `stty -f /dev/cu.usbserial-A4017CQY -clocal`, they do appear to be changed when displayed with a successive call to `stty`.

If I use `select()` to wait for the device to become ready before reading/writing, it reports after a short time that it is ready to write, but never to read. This gels with how `write()` completes without complaint, while `read()` fails. Note that the data written never does actually make it to the device.

The entire test program I wrote to debug this is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define SYSCALL(A) do { ret = A; if (ret == -1) { perror(#A); return -1; } else printf("%s returned %d\n", #A, ret); } while (0)
int ret; /* necessary for SYSCALL */

int main()
{
    struct termios tio;
    char buf[256];
    int fd = open("/dev/cu.usbserial-A4017CQY", 
            O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    fd_set rfds, wfds, xfds;
    struct timeval to;
    to.tv_sec = 5;
    to.tv_usec = 0;

    SYSCALL(tcgetattr(fd, &tio));

    cfmakeraw(&tio);

    tio.c_cflag = CS8|CREAD|CLOCAL;
    tio.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tio.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    cfsetispeed(&tio, B115200);
    cfsetospeed(&tio, B115200);

    SYSCALL(tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tio));

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_ZERO(&wfds);
    FD_ZERO(&xfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &rfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &wfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &xfds);

    int ret = select(fd+1, &rfds, NULL, &xfds, &to);
    if (ret == -1) perror("select");
    else if (ret > 0)
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(fd, &rfds))
            puts("Ready to read");
        if(FD_ISSET(fd, &wfds))
            puts("Ready to write");
        if(FD_ISSET(fd, &xfds))
            puts("Exception!");
    }
    else puts("Timed out!");

    SYSCALL(write(fd, "/home\n", 5));
    SYSCALL(read(fd, buf, 256));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR: You're using the wrong device. Use `/dev/tty.*`, not `/dev/cu.*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a flow control issue. Either loop back join RTS/CTS and DTR/DSR/CD on your cable, have the other end provide control signals, or, as @duskwuff suggests, use the device that ignores flow control.

I see that you are setting `CLOCAL` -- that should work, but some USB devices do not do the right thing. Your description is consistent with the device waiting for modem control signals.

Comment: Eric - This other post does a good job of explaining the difference:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/8632586/3893444