# Choosing between /dev/tty.usbserial vs /dev/cu.usbserial

Tags: macos, serial-port, serial-communication

A PL2303 serial-over-USB device is configured to receive-only data.  There is an explanation of *tty* vs. *cu* here:

*[MacOS: what's the difference between /dev/tty.* and /dev/cu.*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632586/macos-whats-the-difference-between-dev-tty-and-dev-cu)*

That being said, when configuring data collection software, one has to choose either */dev/tty.usbserial* ***or*** */dev/cu.usbserial*.  I would like to understand the facts and the decision-making thought for selecting *tty* or *cu*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The distinction only matters when you use a modem that provides the DCD signal and you're interested in sharing the device between two or more processes: one or more that can occasionally call out, and exactly one that wants to answer calls. In practice, it probably matters for historical things like `uucp`.

For everything that's not a modem or that's not intended to be shared between call-out/call-in processes, you should use the `/dev/cu.*` as this gives you exclusive access to the device.