# What are these device connection names?

Tags: c, linux, tty

I want to connect an Arduino to a linux computer. All devices are listed at `/dev/*`. When I connect for example an original Arduino mega, I get these additional devices:

```
/dev/tty.usbmodem...
/dev/cu.usbmodem...
```

Now when I want to read from the serial port using this C-function:

```
void read_from_serial() {
    int fd = open("/dev/cu.usbmodem14101", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if(fd < 0) {
        printf("Failed to open connection to device.\n");
        return;
    }

    struct termios tty;
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)B115200);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)B115200);

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

    char c;
    while (read(fd, &c, 1) == 1) {
        putchar(c);
    }

    close(fd);
}
```

I need to connect to `/dev/cu...` and not to `/dev/tty...` What is the meaning of cu and tty?

Comment: `man cu` and `man tty`

Comment: okay, but why can't I use tty then?

Comment: `to a linux computer.` Are you sure it's linux and not macos? `why can't I use tty then?` What do you mean? Why can't you? Note that you asked `What is the meaning of cu and tty?` and __not__ "why I can't use tty" or similar. Is the source code anyhow relevant to your question? Please consider asking a separate question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632586/macos-whats-the-difference-between-dev-tty-and-dev-cu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacOS: what's the difference between /dev/tty.\* and /dev/cu.\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632586/macos-whats-the-difference-between-dev-tty-and-dev-cu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are these device connection names?
>
> What is the meaning of cu and tty?

`tty` stands for "TeleTYpewriter", from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_(unix) .

`cu` stands for "Call-Up" device, devices used for calling them up, like modems, from https://pbxbook.com/other/mac-tty.html.